# How to set width and height of images from web services dynamically in listview android?

Tags: android, android-listview

please let me share your ideas.
I need to set original width and height of images or video thumbnail from web services in listview dynamically as like facebook,vine application.Please help me to sort out this issue.
I'm novice to image handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be sure about the image size would be uploaded by application user. At the same time, you can't be sure about the image size (or device size) you should display into the android device, because android devices are coming into the wide range of resolutions!

If you include more details then I would share more details! But as of now I would say, refer [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and decide the scale type you should use for the `ImageView`.

Comment: TanQ for your reply.I need to set images from web services being posted dynamically to avoid image quality issue.for example 300 px*250px images being posted.I will being stretched in nexu5 devices.Because it is very less px for nexus 5 device.

Comment: As I said you would not be able to make sure about the image size being uploaded by user and at the same would not able to make sure about the device size in which you would load image!